# How To Upload Images Directly From An URL to FireBase?

Tags: android, firebase, url, io, firebase-storage

I have an app setup in which i am authenticating a user through Google sign in. And if the user authenticates properly, The user will be allowed to enter to the next activity. As well as the Name, email and profile image of the user from the account will be saved to Firebase.

Now the Problem is that i am able to store the name and the email to the Firebase but i am unable to save the profile image directly from URL from the account to the Firebase.

```java
 GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
                            String F_name = acct.getDisplayName();
                            String L_name = acct.getFamilyName();
                            String email = acct.getEmail(); 
                            final Uri photo = acct.getPhotoUrl();

                            final StorageReference FILEPATH = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile images/"+email +".jpg");


                            FILEPATH.putFile(photo).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                                    Map<String, Object> profileToSave = new HashMap<>();

                                    profileToSave.put("Profile Pic",photo.toString());
                                    docRef.set(profileToSave).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {


                                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),profile.class));
                                            finish();


                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
```

And the following lines are from the error i got

`E/UploadTask: could not locate file for uploading:`

`E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.`

`An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response. Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0`

`E/StorageException: No content provider:`

Looking forward to any suggestions as soon as possible. Let me know if some one got the solution or an other way to do So. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't.. but in reality, there isn't much reason to. If you have the url, you can already use it, so there is no need to upload the file to Firebase. I suggest you simply store the URL in your Realtime Database. Now, to sync this with email/password users (who don't automatically have a profile picture on account creation) and to allow users to update their profile picture:

Let users set their profile picture (by uploading an image to Firebase Storage). Once the upload is complete, get the download URL (of the storage reference!) and update photoUrl in your Realtime Database.

See my code below:

```
storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Log.d(TAG, "before onSuccess: " + user.getPhotoUrl());
                UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                        .setPhotoUri(uri).build();
                user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
                Log.d(TAG, "after onSuccess: " + uri);
                //add new photoUrl to db
                databaseReference.child("photoUrl").setValue(uri.toString());
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure:" + e);
            }
        });
```